# Хук на одну кнопку клавиатуры и на одно окно

Tags: c#, winforms, hook, mouse-event

Я нашёл код глобального хука и использовал его для своего автокликера
Мне нужно что бы программа когда свёрнута имитировала нажатие мышки(что она и делает) но я выбрал в качестве тренировки игру Minecraft, и "кликер" не работает в окне minecraft'a да ещё и срабатывает на нажатие любой кнопки,а не которую мне надо(F)
Код:

```
namespace Vs
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(MouseFlags dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

    //для удобства использования создаем перечисление с необходимыми флагами (константами), которые определяют действия мыши: 
    [Flags]
    enum MouseFlags
    {
        Move = 0x0001, LeftDown = 0x0002, LeftUp = 0x0004, RightDown = 0x0008,
        RightUp = 0x0010, Absolute = 0x8000
    }
    public Form1()
    {

    InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Hook.SetHook();
    }
    public void myfunc()
    {

        bool check = true;
        const int x = 32000;
        const int y = 32000;

        if (check == true) { 
        mouse_event(MouseFlags.Absolute | MouseFlags.Move, x, y, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
        mouse_event(MouseFlags.Absolute | MouseFlags.LeftDown, x, y, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
        mouse_event(MouseFlags.Absolute | MouseFlags.LeftUp, x, y, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
                            }

    }
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // убираем хук 
        Hook.UnHook();

    }
    class Hook
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13; // Номер глобального LowLevel-хука на клавиатуру
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100; // Сообщения нажатия клавиши
        private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = hookProc;
        private static IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;
        public static void SetHook()
        {
            IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _proc, hInstance, 0);
        }
        public static void UnHook()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
        }
        public static IntPtr hookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (code >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                Form1 f1 = new Form1();
                f1.myfunc(); // ошибка
                return (IntPtr)1;
            }
            else
                return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, (int)wParam, lParam);
        }  

}
```

Comment: 1) пожалуйста, отформатируйте код 2) Ссылка вк не к месту, вам туда писать никто не будет 3) если вам надо обрабатывать конкретную кнопку - то и обрабатывайте конкретную кнопку - в чем проблема то?

Comment: Первое что значит отформатировать,второе я попросил,третье: мне нужно что бы она обрабатывалась даже когда форма свёрнута

Comment: в вашем форматировании меня смущают пустые методы, непонятки с отступами, множественные переносы строк в случайных местах, вылезающая из форматирования закрывающая фигурная скобка в конце кода

Comment: второе - попросили и попросили, я вас тоже попросил, ни к чему не принуждаю - все мои просьбы только помогают вам улучшить ваш вопрос и привлечь больше людей, следовать им или нет - вам решать

Comment: Исправил,можете помочь?

Comment: По поводу самого вопроса я не очень разбираюсь (не имел дела с хуками), иначе бы написал вам ответ. Но мне кажется, что вы ставите хук на перехват события окна, но когда окно свернуто, оно скорее всего не получает событий клавиатуры, и потому хук это не перехватывает - но это просто мои мысли, как в реальности я не знаю

Comment: Но ведь если можно по другому сделать,скажите как

Comment: Как я сказал, я не спец, но поглядите например на [глобальные хуки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application)